# Hudson and UCM ClearCase

Tags: ant, hudson, build-automation, clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I have recently put one of our projects on Hudson using the UCM ClearCase plugin. Hudson works well until a configuration changes and then it hangs at update. In ClearCase the user is prompted and asked if they would like to continue (yes/no) when theres a change so im guessing this is where Hudson is hanging.

I have configured Hudson to work with a snapshot view for speed so I would ideally like to avoid switching to a dynamic view.

The project uses ant for the build process.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you have the 'use update' option checked in the ClearCase section of your Hudson job.

What version of the [ClearCase plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/ClearCase+Plugin) are you using?
And what is the exact update command used in the Hudson job logs?

an `update -force -overwrite` would make sure, for instance, to never ask anything to the user.

[image: http://img715.i_mageshack.us/img715/3200/eclipsehudsonucm.png]

Comment: Yes, I do currently have use update checked. Is this the reason for the hang? Unfortunately, one of the dev's deleted the jobs whilst I was away so the logs are no longer available. If "update -force -overwrite" will solve this where should I put this in Hudson?

Comment: @Sion: You can try not checking this option and see if the issue remains. But unless recompiling the plugin, you cannot change the options used by the update command.

Answer (score 0):

Are you mixing scheduled build and ClearCase polling? If there is an update to the stream  before the polling happens Hudson may ask for user input.

As a workaround I have set "cleartool setcs -stream" in the scripts. This makes update gets called twice for the case where it started by polling but does not cause Hudson to wait in the scheduled build.